# Select first element which is inside another element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select my first and last button in this set:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <button>stuff</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>stuff</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>stuff</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can this be done in CSS? I'm trying to use `:first-of-type` and `:first-child` but they aren't working.

Comment: use `ul li:first-child button{//css rules}` and `ul li:last-child button{//css rules}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First button -

```
ul > li:first-child > button
```

Last button -

```
ul > li:last-child > button
```

The direct descendant selector `>` is used to avoid confusion if a list is nested.

http://jsfiddle.net/24tNQ/

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
ul li:first-child button {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```
ul li:last-child button {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the direct descendant selector `>`

```
ul li:first-child > button {
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
ul li:last-child > button {
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

Comment: nice answers divya :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
li:first-of-type button,li:last-of-type button{
    color:red;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/da5c9/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PHLMQ/

```
li:first-child button { background:green}
li:last-child button { background:red}
```